# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' in setting.py Django

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I want to streamline the coding process by running DATABASE_URL from docker-compose files to use setting.py, can you suggest a solution to the error I'm experiencing?

When I use python manage.py migrate I came across this problem.
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse(DATABASE_URL.encode())}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

docker-compose.yml

```bash
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - "mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql"  

  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=mariadb+mariadbconnector://user:mariadb@db:3306/mariadb
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

setting.py

```bash
import os
import dj_database_url

DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.parse(DATABASE_URL.encode())}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `DATABASE_URL` seems to be `None`, you could exec into the docker container and `printenv` in order to see the environment variables. (`docker exec <container_name> printenv`